# KeyListener is not working

Tags: java, awt, keylistener

The following code is not working.  I am trying to move a player left, right, up, and, down using key pressed method but when i press the keys it does not respond.  I did not paste the whole code just the part that moves the box there are other if statements to achieve movement of other contents.

---

```
public class innerClassKeyPressed {


   void  keyPressed( KeyEvent e)
   {
    int key= e.getKeyCode();
    if(key==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
        dx=-1;
    }
     if(key==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){

         dx=1;
    }
    if (key==KeyEvent.VK_UP){
        dy=-1;
    }
     if (key==KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
        dy=1;
     }
      if (key == 82)
     {
          initLevel(currlevel);

     } //R
     if (key == 78)
     {
         currlevel++;
          initLevel(currlevel);
      } 

      if ( (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT ) && ( key  == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT ) && 
      (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP ) && ( key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN )) { 

         return;
       }


        for (int row=0; row < myArray.length; row++)

        {
            for (int column=0; column < myArray[row].length; column++)
            {
                 if( myArray[row][column]==  Contents.PLAYER)                       { 
                        if (myArray[row+dy][column+dx] == Contents.BOX)
                        {

                            if (myArray[row+dy*2][column+dx*2] == Contents.EMPTY)

                             {

                                myArray[row+dy][column+dx]= Contents.PLAYER; 
                                 myArray[row][column]= Contents.EMPTY;

                                myArray[row+dy*2][column+dx*2]= Contents.BOX;
```

Comment: *"I did not paste the whole code"*  It is likely the problem lies in code not shown.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: ok i will post the whole key listener.  Thanks

Comment: *"whole key listener."*  Nobody asked for the 'whole key listener'.  Please ***read*** the linked article before making random guesses as to the meaning of 'SSCCE'.

Comment: @NadirKhan, why don't you start by looking at all the topics found under the "Related" heading on the right hand side of this page. You should always search the forum BEFORE posting a question.

Answer (score 1):

`KeyListeners` are notorious for not working (well actually they do, just not the way you think they should).

The problem with `KeyListener` is that they will only react when the component they are registered to is focusable and has focus (also known as key board focus).

Instead, you should use [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) as they allow to determine the focus state under which they are triggered.

Answer (score 0):

As I'm guessing your using a JFrame and Canvas to draw your player then I'm also going to presume this isnt working because you have not added the KeyListener to the JFrame.

For example:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.addKeyListener(keylistener);
```

Comment: That's a lot of speculation.  Speculation is better reserved for comments.  Given you do not have enough rep. to make comments yet, my advice is to steer clear of questions like this where you are (effectively) guessing.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i think that might be the problem.  I called my keylistener class innerClassKeypressed.  So i added  j.addKeyListener(innerClassKeyPressed); in my main method.  Is that ok?

Comment: This is not a good idea as it's unlikely that the frame will ever receive direct keyboard focus.