# why my java KeyListener doesnt work for my ubuntu?

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I am testing my keyListener in java.

My system in Ubuntu 14.04. I setup a panel in main and init the key listener. I also set focusable to true and do requestFocusInWindow.

But when I run the program, the println never shows up in console. confused of that.

```
package key;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Key extends JPanel{
public void action(){
    KeyListener k = new KeyListener(){
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent k){
            System.out.println("key is pressed!");
        }
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){
            System.out.println("key is typed!");
        }
    };
    this.addKeyListener(k);
    this.setFocusable(true);
    this.requestFocusInWindow();
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(400,300);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    Key k = new Key();
    k.action();
}
}
```

Comment: Because you're using a `KeyListener`, seriously, that thing is so temperamental, it's simpler to just use the [Key Bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) which solves the focus related issues and prompts better code re-use and abstraction

Comment: I'm also hoping that `Key` was actually added to the frame at some point AND the frame was made visible

Comment: This is a common problem, with the same solution, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16409352/keylistener-not-working/16409362#16409362), [exmaple](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21368475/keylistener-not-working-using-applet/21370349#21370349), [exmaple](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16028573/keylistener-is-not-working/16028698#16028698), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18029136/keylistener-not-working-requestfocus-not-fixing-it/18029321#18029321), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27270284/keylistener-is-not-working-in-java/27270454#27270454)

Comment: Hi, my frame shows up. BUT what do you mean by add Key to the frame

Comment: See my first comment, also you might consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Hi, I edit code to runnable example, any advice on that?

Comment: Use the key bindings API and `k` to the frame before it's made visible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> any advice on that?

- Use the [key bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) of `KeyListener`
- Add `k` to `frame` before it's made visible

For example...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Key extends JPanel {

    public void action() {
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Waiting");
        InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();

        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0, false), "press.a");
        actionMap.put("press.a", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                label.setText("Pressed A");
            }
        });
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0, true), "release.a");
        actionMap.put("release.a", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                label.setText("Waiting");
            }
        });

        add(label);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                panel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                frame.add(panel);
                Key k = new Key();
                k.action();
                frame.add(k, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                frame.setSize(400, 300);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```